# mvc+jqm actionlink html text issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm just starting out with MVC, and I'm trying to build a sample, proof of concept page for mvc interaction with jquery-mobile.  I've searched for an answer on this, but I don't think I know enough yet to formulate proper queries.

On my view, I am trying to generate output that functions like this (sampled from the jqm demo site) :

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
        <li><a href="index.html">
            <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
            <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
            <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
        </a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">
            <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
            <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
            <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
            <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
        </a></li>
    </ul>
```

So, I'm working it like this :

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>
          @Html.ActionLink( LargeExpandedMultiContentText, "Edit", new { id = item.SysID })
        </li>
}
```

My question, which I don't know a simple way of asking, is, how, in MVC terms, do I fill the variable, so that the href generated by ActionLink() matches the style I've sampled from the jqm website?

I've tried this, and while it almost works, I'm sure its not the 'right' way, especially when I get to a spot of pulling "Steven Weber" and other strings out the the item/Model...plus it encodes the text, but I'm sure there's a way to deal with that easy enough.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li>
        @{ String txt =  "<h3>Stephen Weber</h3><p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p><p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>         <p class=\"ui-li-aside\"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>";
        }
        @Html.ActionLink( txt, "Edit", new { id = item.SysID })
    </li>
}
```

Thanks, I appreciate your help

Brian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure it's possible to use `Html.ActionLink` to build such a complex action link. That said, the Html Helpers are just supposed to be helper functions to make your life easier by giving you shortcuts to render HTML in ways commonly required. You don't **need** to use them. In this case, I think instead you should use a normal html tag, and `Url.Action` to create the correct URL.

If you wanted to include this information within an enumerable model I'd probably do something like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(item.Action)">
        <h3>@item.Name</h3>
        <p><strong>@item.Title</strong></p>
        <p>@item.Message</p>
        <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>@item.Time</strong>@item.TimePeriod</p>
    </a></li>
}
```

Note: the function you were looking for to display contents without encoding them is `@Html.Raw`

Comment: Thanks for the @Html.Raw hint...I knew I'd seen that somewhere...can you answer, by any chance, the part of the question about doing a nested code block withing the foreach ?

Comment: Happy to help if I can, but please reiterate what the nested code block part of the question is. I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: in my original post, the 3rd code block...inside the foreach, I was wondering if thats the right way to handle that kind of idea, the the txt variable, and if that reduces me to string concatenation to build out the html, or if there's a more MVC way.... For the record, I've flipped all my code to your recommendation, and things appear to be working grandly...thanks!

Comment: I think putting your html in a string inside a view just so you can then reprint the string in html form is a bad idea. If you did that you'd be obfuscating your html needlessly. Views in MVC are meant to be designed such that they isolate your html and style from your coding logic. So try to make your views look as much like transparent html as possible. That's what I was going for in the example I gave you. It's just html with pieces of the model used where necessary.

Comment: right, but to the more general question, whats the right way to do it, if I had too....are you saying there is no right way...like the old adage "if you have a problem that requires regex...now you have TWO problems!" ?  IE, if I find myself in a spot like that, I've taken a wrong turn a few steps ago ?

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure I'm following. If you're forced to use a string then I think Html.Raw is "right". That said, I can't think of a reason you'd need to create html as a string in the view just to redisplay it as html. Whenever I find myself using Html.Raw it's because I need to display an already built html string created somewhere else. You might want to ask this as a separate question if it's still bothering you, maybe others would have more elaborate answers.

Comment: no, you're following right...I think I am just beating a dead horse that should never have lived in the first place :D ... thanks for the chat!

Answer (score 0):

In answer to my other 'half question' I found this resource...

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx

I believe the "razor delegate" item there at the bottom would fit the need I had.

```
@{
  Func<dynamic, object> b = 
   @<strong>@item</strong>;
}

@b("Bold this")
```